# GitHub won't let me push to remote folder (in Xcode)

Tags: xcode, git, github

I'm trying to set up a GitHub Repo for an existing Project (in Xcode). I'm already logged in with my GitHub Account. But as soon as I try to Push a commit to the Remote Repo, this Window Pops Up[image]

I can't select anything. How can I fix that?

Comment: This is not because of Git or GitHub, it's something XCode itself is doing to you. (Why it's doing that remains a mystery to me.)

Comment: @torek Really? This is just the kind of thing I would expect to see if this is a local repo with no remote.

Comment: @matt: if that's the case, XCode should be saying so. Perhaps it is, but that seems like a roundabout way of doing it: offering you selector boxes where it's impossible to select anything is downright unfriendly. Surely they could notice and raise an error box instead.

Comment: @torek I didn't say Xcode's Git support doesn't suck. I only said that this is what Xcode normally does in this situation. But my point is, the mistake the user is making is a Git mistake, not an Xcode problem. Removing the Git and GitHub tags is wrong. Even if Xcode were not involved, you can't push a local repo that has no remote (unless, of course, you specify the remote URL as part of the push command).

Comment: OK, I've put the tags back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't push a local repo that is not associated with a remote repo (known, for short, as a "remote"). Give this repo a remote. You can either make one at GitHub now, or associate this repo with a repo at GitHub that you have created already. Here's how to do that using Xcode's interface:

[image]

Personally, though, I never use Xcode's Git interface for much of anything; it's atrocious. Learn to use the command line; you'll be much happier (in my opinion).